# Re-route from Internal IP to to Domain URL in Apache using ProxyPass

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, httpd, mod-proxy

I have a server with IP 100.00.0.00 that hosts multiple applications one of them has the domain example.com.

I have an external application that will request from my server like below but the endpoint is in the example.com application:

`http://100.00.0.00/api/sdp/subscription?ProcessedTime=2018-07-31%2010%3A39%3A45&channelId=0&chargingType=ACT&fee=null&lifeCycle=G&msisdn=776274848&nextRenewDate=2019-12-13%2010%3A39%3A45`

My application is supposed to read the parameters on:

`http://example.com/api/sdp/subscription?ProcessedTime=2018-07-31%2010%3A39%3A45&channelId=0&chargingType=ACT&fee=null&lifeCycle=G&msisdn=776274848&nextRenewDate=2019-12-13%2010%3A39%3A45`

I have tried and its not working:

`ProxyPass /api/ http://example.com/api`

Please help, what method can I use?

Comment: Is example.com a name for ip 100.00.0.00 or for some other address? In other words, is are example.com and 100.00.0.00 different hosts or the same?

Comment: 100.00.0.00 is the IP of the server and it contains several applications with different domain names. example.com is a domain of one of the applications

Answer (score 0):

If 100.00.0.00 is the IP of the server, that you don't want to proxy.

Just add

```
ServerAlias 100.00.0.00
```

to the definition of the example.com VirtualHost. Or make sure it is the first VirtualHost in your configuration. This makes example.com the default VirtualHost that is used if no other VirtualHost can be found.